# Rails/RSpec "it" method description and string interpolation

Tags: rspec-rails

Following is my RSpec code snippet:

```
describe UsersController do
  def mock_authentication_token(user, token_string)
    ...
    ...
  end

  def create_data
    @date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    today = Time.now
    @today_str = today.strftime(@date_format)
    ...
    ..
    ..
  end

  before do
    @current_user = Factory(:client)
    authtoken_str = "client auth token string"
    mock_authentication_token(@current_user, authtoken_str)
  end

  context "action: index" do
    before do
      create_data
      @params = @params.merge(limit: 5)
    end

    it "should return the more link with date set to 1 second ahead of #{@today_str}" do
      get :index, @params

      body = JSON.parse response.body

      ...
      ...
      ...
    end
end
```

This example **it "should return the more link with date set to 1 second ahead of #{@today_str}" do** when fails it doesn't print the value of instance variable @today_str set by helper method **create_data**, in the failed example description.

It just prints: *should return the more link with date set to 1 second ahead of*

It seems that **it** method doesn't allow string interpolation.Is this really the case? If yes how do I achieve the desired behavior.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Comment: What's stopping you from using "the time now" in the description? It seems more descriptive and meaningful to see that you are testing with the *time exactly now* than with a timestamp around the time that you ran the test.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec resets the class instance `@` variables after each `it` block.

For instance:

```
describe 'it blocks' do

  before :all
    @reset = 0
    @@global = 'will break tests'
  end

  it 'should increment' do
    @reset += 1
  end

  it "shouldn't forget it, either" do
    # but it does
    @reset.should eql 0
  end

  it 'does remember class-level variables, though' do
    @@global += ' for sure'
  end

  it 'can be demonstrated via' do
    @@global.split(' ').should > 3
  end

  # this is not the same @reset as what's in `before :all`.
  this_is_blank = @reset
  it "won't interpolate #{this_is_blank} because it's an instance level variable" do
    true.should be true
  end

  local = 'might as well hard code them into your descriptions at this point'
  it "Doesn't matter anymore because you #{local}" do
    true.should eql true
  end

  it "won't get here because class-level variables #{@@global}" do
    (2 + 2).should eql 5
  end

end
```

Looks like you'll have to name your spec tests more generically. I have, anyway.